# Variables passing from servlet to JSP not working

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, jakarta-ee, get

I am working on a J2EE project, and I want to have this architecture:

JSP1: index.jsp

Servlet: Search

JSP2: results.jsp

I want to insert some data in jsp1, use it in servlet treatment then show the results in jsp2.

Thus, I cannot have the results in jsp2. I also tried to just put a test variable and send it from servlet to jsp2 but it did not work neither.
How can I fix this? 
Here is my jsp1:

```
    `<%@ page langua`ge="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<form action="search " method="post">
   var1: <input type="text" name="var1" size="20">
   var2: <input type="text" name="var2" size="20">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</h
```

Here is my servlet class

```
     package servlet;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import forms.WriteExcel;

    public class Search extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Search() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            String var1 = request.getParameter("var1");
            String var2 = request.getParameter("var2");
            String[] info = { var1, var2 };
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> files;
            String resultsExcelPath = "";
            try {
                files = Main(info);
                resultsExcelPath = WriteExcel.csvFile(info, files);
                request.setAttribute("files", files);
                request.setAttribute("excel", excel);
request.setAttribute("variable test", "just a variable to test jsp2");

            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

this is my jsp2 : results.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>variable : ${variable}</p>
    <p>var2 : ${var2}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
<servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlet.Search</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Search</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>




</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the map **params**: Ex: **${params.var1}**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>variable : ${params.var1}</p>
    <p>var2 : ${params.var2}</p>
</body>
</html>
```